# how to replace specific spaces with new line using python script?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have about 3000 number of txt files in a folder directory and now i want to replace some spaces in txt files with new line.
for example:

```
Ottoman Empire Spain
Japan Sweden
United States Tuscany
Brazil United States
Mexico United States
United States Brazil
United States Mexico
Romania Belgium
Spain Sweden
Spain United States
Sweden Belgium
Japan Kingdom of Italy
```

i want to convert above list to following:

```
Ottoman Empire
Spain
Japan
Sweden
United States
Tuscany
Brazil
United States
Mexico
United States
United States
Brazil
United States
Mexico
Romania
Belgium
Spain
Sweden
Spain
United States
Sweden
Belgium
Japan
Kingdom of Italy
```

I written following script for it:

```
import os
import re

# Define the directory path where the text files are located
directory = r'E:\Desktop\Copy'

# Define the regex patterns and their replacements
patterns = [
    (r'\(Netherlands\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Portugal\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Greece\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Romania\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Baden\) \(Tuscany\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Portugal\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Netherlands\) \(Romania\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Ottoman Empire\) \(Spain\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Japan\) \(Sweden\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Tuscany\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Mexico\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Mexico\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Romania\) \(Belgium\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Sweden\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Sweden\) \(Belgium\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Japan\) \(Kingdom of Italy\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Sweden\) \(Bulgaria\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Romania\) \(Sweden\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Japan\) \(Ottoman Empire\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Romania\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Japan\) \(Ethiopia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Belgium\) \(Portugal\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Japan\) \(Republic of China\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Japan\) \(Romania\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Ethiopia\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Republic of China\) \(Austria-Hungary\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Sweden\) \(Portugal\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Czechoslovakia\) \(Ethiopia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Yugoslavia\) \(Czechoslovakia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Kingdom of Italy\) \(Russian SFSR\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Ethiopia\) \(Belgium\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Weimar Republic\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(N. Germany\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Czechoslovakia\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Romania\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Kingdom of Italy\) \(Soviet Union\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Iran\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Greece\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Greece\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Afghanistan\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Afghanistan\) \(Mexico\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Kingdom of Italy\) \(New Zealand\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Saxony\) \(Baden\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Poland\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Poland\) \(Romania\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Poland\) \(North Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Poland\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Pakistan\) \(Italy\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Czechoslovakia\) \(Romania\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Poland\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(India\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(Poland\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Czechoslovakia\) \(North Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Czechoslovakia\) \(Poland\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(North Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Czechoslovakia\) \(Indonesia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(North Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'Indonesia \(West Germany\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Portugal\) \(Denmark\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Baden\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Italy\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Indonesia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(West Germany\) \(Czechoslovakia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Soviet Union\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(West Germany\) \(Spain\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(North Korea\) \(Yugoslavia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(K. Two Sicilies\) \(Netherlands\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Saxony\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Vietnam\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(North Korea\) \(Spain\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Mexico\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(West Germany\) \(North Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Egypt\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Pakistan\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(West Germany\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Spain\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(Taiwan\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Egypt\) \(Taiwan\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Egypt\) \(Brazil\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Pakistan\) \(Taiwan\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Portugal\) \(Belgium\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iraq\) \(South Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Pakistan\) \(Poland\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Pakistan\) \(Egypt\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(West Germany\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Portugal\) \(Sweden\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iran\) \(France\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(Egypt\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iran\) \(Egypt\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(India\) \(North Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Ukraine\) \(Egypt\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iran\) \(Ukraine\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Taiwan\) \(Egypt\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Italy\) \(Iraq\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iraq\) \(France\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Myanmar\) \(Taiwan\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Syria\) \(Taiwan\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iraq\) \(Myanmar\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Indonesia\) \(Thailand\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iraq\) \(Vietnam\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Indonesia\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Indonesia\) \(France\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Egypt\) \(Myanmar\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Saxony\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Saudi Arabia\) \(Thailand\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Iran\) \(South Korea\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(K. Two Sicilies\) \(Denmark\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Kingdom of Hanover\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Netherlands\) \(Mexico\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Belgium\) \(K. Two Sicilies\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Kingdom of Hanover\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Denmark\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(United States\) \(Belgium\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Portugal\) \(Kingdom of Hanover\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Mexico\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Saxony\) \(Denmark\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Portugal\) \(Mexico\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Brazil\) \(Kingdom of Hanover\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Haiti\) \(United States\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Spain\) \(Bavaria\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Denmark\) \(Mexico\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Denmark\) \(Saxony\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    (r'\(Denmark\) \(Paraguay\)', r'\\1\n\\2'),
    # Add more patterns here following the same format
]

# Iterate over the files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        # Read the contents of the file
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            contents = file.read()

        # Apply the regex replacements
        for pattern, replacement in patterns:
            contents = re.sub(pattern, replacement, contents)

        # Write the modified contents back to the file
        with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(contents)

print("Replacements completed.")
```

when i run this script i get `Replacements completed.` but when i check txt files then no any changes applied to txt files!

when i change `\\1` and `\\2` to `\1` and `\2` in my script then i get following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Desktop\scr\OCR\tetetert.py", line 152, in <module>
    contents = re.sub(pattern, replacement, contents)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 185, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 317, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 308, in _compile_repl
    return _parser.parse_template(repl, pattern)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\_parser.py", line 1072, in parse_template
    addgroup(int(this[1:]), len(this) - 1)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\_parser.py", line 1008, in addgroup
    raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
re.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 1
```

where is problem?

Comment: If you're using r-strings, `\\1` should be just `\1`, and similarly for `\2`.

Comment: @muru i edited script and get multiple error this time!

Comment: And? Edit the question with the errors, then

Comment: @muru edited. check error.

Comment: Groups are just `(...)`, not `\(...\)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-15

Comment: @muru tnq very much - your idea solved problem. if it possible please send answer to my topic then i accept your answer for problem.

Comment: Depending on your data you could use one pattern: [`(?i)^(\w+(?: (?:empire|states))?) (\w.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/mXhncj/1) You'd need to add more alternations after `|states` for each country that consists of multiple words, e.g. `|of italy`... replace with the [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) values and newline between: `\1\n\2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has an excess of backslashes:

- With raw strings, `\1` should be just `\1` and not `\\1`
- Groups don't need `\` - you can use just `(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Manually listing hundreds of replacing cases is not an efficient solution to this problem. Instead, match all country names using branches (e.g. `Netherlands|United States|...`) and join that list of matches with a `\n`:

```py
countries = [
  'Netherlands',
  'United States',
  'Portugal',
  'Greece',
  ...
]

def format_country_name_files(file):
  content = file.read()
  countries_escaped = (re.escape(country) for country in countries)
  matches = re.findall('|'.join(countries_escaped), content)
  
  file.seek(0)
  file.write('\n'.join(matches))
  file.truncate()
```

Try it:

```py
with open('.txt', 'r+') as file:
  format_country_name_files(file)

# File content:
'''
Ottoman Empire
Spain
Japan
Sweden
United States
...
'''
```